# Is it OK to remove my own low quality question with decent/good answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, self-delete

Some time ago, I have put [this low quality question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290452/wouldnt-be-nice-to-have-user-reputation-league-page-across-all-sites-or-shortly). It received a two decent answers, one providing a link to a query that retrieves relevant information related to the subject.

**Question:** Is it OK to remove the question? This also means wiping fairly decent answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.** The system will actually *prevent* you from removing questions with at least one up-voted (i.e. helpful) answer. Habitually removing your posts may even flag that content for moderator attention.

The reason is that once you post a question or answer to this site, those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future.

This is an underlying philosophy of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. My particular case is: it is useful for me, but the number of downvotes suggests that it is not an useful question.

Comment: "deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it... is seen as so overtly hostile that it does impose a pretty stiff penalty..." ([Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601))

Answer (score 11):

As already said, it isn't even possible. Questions with upvoted answers cannot be deleted (without a moderator intervening). If you have a real need to delete the question then flag the post.

It's worth noting though that specifically on Meta, a heavily downvoted question doesn't necessarily mean it is low-quality; just that other users disagreed with the post (and -5 — which your question currently is — isn't really that low).

As [What's Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)  says:

> #### Voting is different on meta.
>
> ...voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

Comment: This really answers my question. I was used to voting on the SO, where -5 is really bad. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it is something new users should probably be made more aware of when posting suggestions!

Comment: @Cai you might want to add "... a heavily downvoted question doesn't **necessarily** mean ...". I've seen plenty of low quality meta posts and have downvoted them for being low quality.

Comment: @Dragonrage very true, good point

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to. The site will let you try, then tell you that you're not allowed to delete it because it has already received an up voted answer.

So the answer can be inferred: it's not okay.

In exceptional circumstances, a mod can delete the question anyway. Alternatively, you can request to have a post dissociated from your account. But a low score isn't an exceptional circumstance and these two options are unlikely to be available.